# MYSQL UPDATE from SELECT INNER JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hello :)  I am fairly new to using INNER JOIN and still trying to comprehend it's logic which I think I am sort of beginning to understand.  After being across a few different articles on the topic I have generated a query for finding duplicates in my table of phone numbers.
My table structure is as such:

```
+---------+-------+
| PhoneID | Phone |
+---------+-------+
```

Very simple.  I created this query:

```
SELECT A.PhoneID, B.PhoneID FROM T_Phone A
INNER JOIN T_Phone B
ON A.Phone = B.Phone AND A.PhoneID < B.PhoneID
```

Which returns the ID of a phone that matches another one.  I don't know how to word that properly so here is an example output:

```
+---------+---------+
| PhoneID | PhoneID |
+---------+---------+
|   17919 |   17969 |
|   17919 |   22206 |
|   17919 |   23837 |
|   17920 |   17970 |
|   17920 |   22203 |
|   17920 |   23834 |
|   17921 |   17971 |
|   17921 |   22225 |
|   17921 |   22465 |
|   17921 |   24011 |
|   17921 |   24047 |
|   17922 |   17972 |
|   17922 |   22198 |
|   17922 |   23879 |
|   17923 |   17973 |
|   17923 |   22199 |
|   17923 |   23880 |
+---------+---------+
```

You can note that on the left there is repeating IDs, the phone number that matches will be on the right (These are just the IDs of said numbers).  what I am trying to accomplish, is to actually change a join table relative to the ID on the right.  The join table structure is as such:

```
+----------+-----------+
| T_JoinID | T_PhoneID |
+----------+-----------+
```

Where T_JoinID is a larger object with a collection of those T_PhoneIDs, hence the join table.  What I want to do is take a row from the original match query, and find the right side PhoneID in the join table, then update that item in the Join to be equal to the left side PhoneID.  Repeating this for each row.

It's sort of a way to save space and get rid of matching numbers, I can just point the matching ones to the original and use that as a reference when I need to retrieve it.

After that I need to actually delete the original numbers that I reset the reference for but...  This seems like a job for 2 or 3 different queries.

EDIT:
Sorry I know I didn't include enough detail.  Here is some additional info:
My exact table structure is not the same as here but I am only using the columns that I listed so I didn't consider the fact that any of the others would matter. Most of the tables have a unique ID that is auto incremented.  The phone table has carrier, type, ect columns.  The additional columns I felt were irrelevant to include, but if there is a solution that includes the auto incremented ID of each table, let me know :)  Anyway, I sort of found a solution, using multiple queries though I am still interested to learn and apply knowledge based on this question.  So I have a that join table that I mentioned.  It might look something like this for the expected results.  There is a before and after table in one sorry for poor formatting.

```
+--------------------+---------+----------+---------+
| Join Table Results |         |          |         |
+--------------------+---------+----------+---------+
| Before             |         | After    |         |
| Join               | Table   | Join     | Table   |
| PersonID           | PhoneID | PersonID | PhoneID |
| 1                  | 1       | 1        | 1       |
| 1                  | 2       | 1        | 2       |
| 1                  | 3       | 1        | 3       |
| 2                  | 4       | 2        | 1       |
| 2                  | 5       | 2        | 5       |
| 2                  | 6       | 2        | 6       |
| 3                  | 7       | 3        | 5       |
| 3                  | 8       | 3        | 5       |
| 3                  | 9       | 3        | 5       |
| 3                  | 10      | 3        | 8       |
| 3                  | 11      | 3        | 9       |
+--------------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

So you can see that in the before columns, 7, 8, and 9 would all be duplicate phone numbers in the PhoneID - PhoneID relationship table I posted originally.  After the query I wanted to retrieve the duplicates using the PhoneID - PhoneID comparison and take the ones that match, to change the join table in a way that I have shown directly above.  So 7, 8, 9 all turn to 5.  Because 5 is the original number, and 7, 8, 9 coincidentally were duplicates of 5.  So I am basically pointing all of them to 5, and then deleting what would have been 7, 8, 9 in my Phone table since they all have a new relationship to 5.  Is this making sense? xD  It sounds outrageous typing it out.

End Edit

How can I improve my query to accomplish this task?  Is it possible using an UPDATE statement?  I was also considering just looping through this output and updating each row individually but I had a hope to just use a single query to save time and code.  Typing it out makes me feel a tad obnoxious but I had hope there was a solution out there!

Thank you to anyone in advance for taking your time to help me out :)  I really appreciate it.  If it sounds outlandish, let me know I will just use multiple queries.

Comment: Hey Pixel! Although you can use an operation to achieve this by following the exact logic you listed yourself, in reverse, I suggest altering your architecture instead. I don't have access to your data and I can't know for sure if I am right, but from your description there appears to be a lot of redundancy in your architectural design and structurally this can be your application's downfall in the long run. Instead of attempting to perform maintenance tasks from the get-go, its better to alter the architecture so thats not needed. A unique key index works wonders when properly applied :-)

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to achieve, can you give a description of your table and the fix it needs ?

Comment: Don't expect that an update can "auto-differentiate" between phone_ids on the right with repeated phone_ids in the  left column. You need to give us more  relevant **sample data** and the **expected result** (which you have not supplied).  I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Ok I edited the question.   I hope that it makes sense now.  I agree there could be redundancy and while my table structure is actually slightly different I am intrigued to learn, Would you care to explain more what you might expect to see in a more efficient situation? Yes I am sorry it's quite the mess.  In very simple terms, I want to find duplicate phone numbers in my table, delete them, but only if they belong to the same person.  Hence the ID matching process.  I wasn't expecting it to auto-differentiate :) Let me know if you need more from edit :)